# MapControl render distance

Tags: uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

working with the MapControl in the 3d view, I've realized that when changing pitch angle, specially when getting nearer to the earth surface, the furthest surface textures and wireframe resolution downgrades. I suppose that this is to achieve a better response or agility in the drawing of the scene but, is there any way to make somehow the render of the scene with more detail, better textures at further distances and surface 3d models?

Below the comparation between two positions.

[image]

The distance to the a,b,c and d elements it's in both scenes almost identical, but there's a visible difference between the marked zones.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean when you zoom in on the map, the part farthest from the map appear more blurred? When you tested the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) about 3D views, will the same issue occur?

Comment: Not zooming, but changing pitch angle and getting nearer to the surface. While left tapping moving up and down the mouse.

Comment: What I'm trying to show is the unwanted rendering mode and the question is how I can tell to the scene renderer to use more detailed textures and surface models to further distance.
BTW, the behavior in the official sample is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the expected behavior. It's simply not possible to draw the highest resolution data all the way to the horizon - it would explode exponentially the amount of data required. The map control will progressively fall off in levels of detail shown as the distance from the camera increases. All 3D rendering engines do this.
There is currently no way to control this at the API level. There is logic internal to the control which will change the rate of detail falloff based on the particular hardware. So for example you will see better detail on a system with a fast multi-core CPU and dedicated GPU than you will on a laptop with integrated graphics. You might try rendering your scene on a more capable system. You might also try adjusting the DPI settings on the system as the map control will also take into account system DPI when selecting the level of detail.

Comment: I didn't expect to draw the highest detailed scene all the way to the horizon, but at the double of distance for example. And, anyway, I don't think that to draw this scene it needs a lo of computational power, computers are capable of more than that.

Comment: The map control will try to select a level of detail based on your hardware to maintain at least 30FPS during animations. Anything lower results in a poor user experience. Even pushing the level of detail out one more level would result in a huge drop in performance as you now have to download and render 4x the data.